# Create data table from an excel file using OleDb with empty column

Tags: c#, excel, import, oledb

I am creating the data table from an excel file, without header, using the following code:

```
connExcel.Open();
cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT F1, F2 From [" + SheetName + "]";
oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
oda.Fill(dt);
connExcel.Close();
```

The problem is, when one of the columns is empty (let's say that F1 column has one row with the value "abc" and the column F2 is empty), then creating of the data table will failed with this error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

Can you please help me, how to create that table just with empty fields for this non existing column. I tried so many options, but nothing really works.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? What has or hasn't worked?

Comment: Anything with changing SQL command (change the null value to the empty value) doesn't work.